# Routing in pretty url in yii2

Tags: yii2, friendly-url

I'm trying to use spanjeta/yii2-backup
For Project GM it works fine. here I'm not using prettyurl
For Projectamitopticals I'm getting 404 error.I'm using pretty url here.
I'm providing comparative codes below
GM - the routing -

```
[
                        'url' => Url::to(['/backup']),
                        'label' => 'Backup',
                        'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-send',
                        'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('c_billing-person'),
                    ],
```

Amitopticals - the routing

```
[
                        'url' => Url::to(['/backup']),
                        'label' => 'Backup',
                        'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt',
                    ],
```

Output screenshot in GM
[image]
Output screenshot of Amitopticals
[image]
Log of GM
[image]
Amitopticals Log
[image]

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it out
Changed rules for pretty url -
Previous pretty url rule

```
'rules' => [
                    '<alias:>' => 'site/<alias>',
            ],
```

Corrected pretty url rule

```
'rules' => [
                    '<alias:\W+>' => 'site/<alias>',
            ],
```

Thanks everyone.